# Javascript wait for a function to return

Tags: javascript

I have a function "add_floor(xxx)" in a loop (see bellow) that take some time to complete, so i would like to know how to wait for the return of this function before moving to the next step which is in my case "add dawfeature points". I understand that I could use a callback method but then I would need to restart the complete loop that goes over the json elements in the calledback function. Not really sexy, so is there a way to avoid this ?

```
function add_maps_from_json(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.maps.length; i++) {
    // add the maps to the combox box and display last one 
    add_floor(json.maps[i].mapName);

    // add the dawfeature points to the map
    for (var j = 0; i < json.maps[i].APs.length; j++) {
      var idx = find_map_index(); 
      console.log(idx);
      var map = mapObjectArray[idx];
      etc...
      etc...

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the only way it wouldn't just follow on from previous code is if you're creating anonymous functions or doing ajax calls or any timeout functions??

Comment: Are there any AJAX calls here?  Otherwise, this should be synchronous.  Meaning it *will* wait until it's done before it returns.  If you are using AJAX calls, the *only way* would be with callbacks.

Comment: What `add_floor()` does? Assync calls?

Comment: @RocketHazmat "synchronous" thank you, much better than 'follow on from previous code' lol

Comment: JS is synchronous. Only one line of code can execute at once. If your function takes a long time to run, your calling code will wait that length of time.

Comment: Hi, no ajax call, the add_floor function just creates an openlayers map and add some layers, but it does load images and I use the "myImage.onload" event in order to make sure the image is fully loaded before adding them to the map. That might be the problem...

Comment: There's your problem! `onload` is an DOM *event*, DOM event handlers are called *asynchronously*. You'll probably need to rework this a bit, perhaps make `add_floor` return a promise which is resolved when *all* images are loaded and added.

Comment: Take a look at using continuations (do a web search for "javascript continuations"). It might address the issues you have with using callbacks.

Comment: take a look at my answer, it would probably meet your need.

Comment: Hi Merhan, Mattias I will try both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have said you have to add a callback parameter to `add_floor` and for managing your loop you can do `async loop`, like this:

```
//change the add_floor function
function add_floor(mapName, callback){
    //your code
    //you probably have some kind of ajax call or setTimeout
    //then call your callback after your ajax response or timer callback
    //....
    callback();
    //....
}

function add_maps_from_json(json) {
    doLoop(json, 0)
}

function doLoop(json, i) {
    if(i < json.maps.length) return;
    add_floor(json.maps[i].mapName, function () {
        // add the dawfeature points to the map
        for (var j = 0; i < json.maps[i].APs.length; j++) {
            var idx = find_map_index();
            console.log(idx);
            var map = mapObjectArray[idx];
            //etc...
            //etc...

        }
        doLoop(json, i + 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the function return a value to a variable. That way the program will pause until the function as run. Like this:

```
var maps = add_maps_from_json(json);
```

Or you can use plugin.js and do module calls.

http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html

Comment: Hi the return value trick doesn't work, I will look at the plugin.js

Answer (score 1):

If `add_floor` doesn't do an ajax call, then your code will work fine as it is now.

If `add_floor` DOES do an ajax call, then you can put the inner `for` loop inside a separate function that you then use as the callback for the ajax call in `add_floor`.

Comment: There are other ways of creating a non-blocking call besides using Ajax--for instance, web workers, or using setTimeout (as the [Clumpy library](http://www.tumuski.com/code/clumpy/overview/) does to simulate non-blocking loops).